# Outra palavra para nomear sem aprovação

Tags: uso-de-palavras, palavra-para-ideia, termos

O Presidente do Brasil *nomeia* candidatos, por exemplo Ministros de Tribunais Superiores, e o Senado *aprova* ou *rejeita* o candidato.

Mas há uma palavra específica para quando uma autoridade (legalmente) só insere uma pessoa num cargo sem precisar a aprovação de outro órgão?

Posso usar *inserir*, como eu fiz aqui, por exemplo?

Comment: No Brasil também usamos "nomear" para o ato de escolher uma determinada pessoa para um determinado cargo sem a aprovação de outrem.  Os Ministros de Estado, escolhidos pelo Presidente da República, não precisam de uma aprovação de nenhum outro órgão.  O Governador do Estado do Rio de Janeiro nomeia seus secretários, acessores, etc, sem precisar da aprovação dos deputados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponho que o princípio é semelhante ao da *Appointments Clause* da constitutuição americana, na qual o Brasil se inspira nalguns pontos, que usa os termos *nominate* (primeira fase, feito apenas pelo presidente) e *appoint* (segunda fase, com o consentimento do Senado).

Uma opção que me ocorre é «instalar no cargo». No entanto, os termos *nomear*, *indicar* e *designar* são todos usados para o ato de atribuir um cargo, independentemente de haver ou não participação de outro órgão. Repare-se nas definições do Aulete para [nomeação](http://www.aulete.com.br/nomea%C3%A7%C3%A3o):

> 2. Atribuição de um cargo público ou privado por autoridade competente.
> 3. Escolha de alguém para cargo, função ou dignidade
> 4. O direito de escolher ou nomear para o exercício de emprego ou função: *Pertence ao governo a nomeação dos juízes.*

Portanto os significados de nomeação não incluem apenas o ato de escolher um candidato, mas também de lhe atribuir finalmente o cargo.